# How do I not have an array emptied after a function gets reset so it can continue?

Tags: javascript, html

**Intro:** 
I am trying to make rock, paper and scissors(rps).

**Issue:** 
I am trying to have two different options saved in my function so I can make a functional game. However every time my array gets reset. which makes it so I can't use the user inputs for rps.

**Current code:**

```js
function game(input) {
  var playerMoves = [];
  if (playerMoves.length < 2) {
    playerMoves.push(input);
  } else {
    playerMoves = [];
  }
  console.log(playerMoves);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#player_turn {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.images {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, paper, scissors!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="player_won"></h1>
  <h1>Player <span id="player_turn">1</span> pick an option!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img onclick="game('rock')" class="images" src="https://therockplacellc.com/wp-content/themes/the-rock-place/i/rock.png" id="rock">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img onclick="game('paper')" class="images" src="https://big.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/solaris/general/TP-Roll.png?mtime=20191210094103&focal=none" id="paper">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img onclick="game('scissors')" class="images" src="https://nl.mouser.com/images/marketingid/2020/microsites/177933245/scissors.PNG" id="scissors">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**"Dev" note:** 
If you think anything is outdated/not useful. Please lmk, I am 100% open to all types of input.

Comment: OH my bad, I fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `playerMoves` declaration outside of the function:

```js
var playerMoves = []

function game(input) {
  if (playerMoves.length < 2) {
    playerMoves.push(input);
    console.log(playerMoves);
  } else {
    playerMoves = [];
  }

}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#player_turn {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.images {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, paper, scissors!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="player_won"></h1>
  <h1>Player <span id="player_turn">1</span> pick an option!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img onclick="game('rock')" class="images" src="https://therockplacellc.com/wp-content/themes/the-rock-place/i/rock.png" id="rock">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img onclick="game('paper')" class="images" src="https://big.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/solaris/general/TP-Roll.png?mtime=20191210094103&focal=none" id="paper">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img onclick="game('scissors')" class="images" src="https://nl.mouser.com/images/marketingid/2020/microsites/177933245/scissors.PNG" id="scissors">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh sh*t thanks! May I ask if you know how I can get it to skip the empty console.log? (I hope this makes sense).

Comment: @Lar I've moved the console log inside the `if` statement so it won't log an empty array.